# Django 1.4.1 and using natural keys in deserializing

Tags: django, django-models, deserialization

Following the Django docs on deserialization, in my `models.py` I've created the class:

```
class PersonManager(models.Manager):
    def get_by_natural_key(self, name):
        return self.get(name=name)

class Person(models.Model):
    objects = PersonManager()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True, blank=False, null=False)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    author = models.ForeignKey(Person)

    def __unicode__(self):
            return self.title
```

I've also created a fixture for Person, "person.json",

```
[
    { 
        "pk": null,
        "model": "myapp.person", 
        "fields": {
            "name": "josh",
        }
     }
]
```

and for Book, "book.json",

```
[
    { 
        "pk": null,
        "model": "myapp.book", 
        "fields": {
            "title": "my book",
            "author": ["josh"]
        }
     }
]
```

The fixtures are saved in the 'fixtures' folder.

I then do `python manage.py sql myapp` and `python manage.py syncdb`, and then `python manage.py loaddata persondata.json`. This works. (I can see the entered data on the admin page and I get a good insert count message back.)

Then I do `python manage.py loaddata bookdata.json` and I get the following error message:

`DeserializationError: [u"'[u'josh']' value must be an integer."]`

How can that be? Why is Django insisting that I use an integer for the primary key, when I've declared the `PersonManager`? What have I missed?

(NB. This is all working fine when I give `author` `pk` directly as an integer.)

Comment: My bad, I meant to mark the other one as a duplicate of this. The other question had an accepted answer, so I wanted to make sure that this one had a reference to that. Removed flag, but here is the answered possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12577446/django-natural-key-for-fixtures-give-deserialization-error

Answer (score 1):

Your manager method has the wrong name. It should be `get_by_natural_key` rather than `get_by_unique_key`.