# Django Natural Key for Fixtures Give Deserialization Error

Tags: python, django, yaml, fixtures, natural-key

I've seen a few similar questions to this on SO, but none seem to answer my particular problem. I'm new to Django and was guiding myself by the instructions at [this page](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/serialization/#natural-keys) to allow myself to use natural keys to load fixtures. Nevertheless, I'm getting Deserialization errors because Django wants an integer for a foreign key and can't seem to map my natural key to an integer primary key as is noted in the instructions. Specifically, my relevant models code is:

```
class GraphTypeManager(models.Manager):
    def get_by_natural_key(self, type):
        return self.get(type=type)
class GraphType(models.Model):
    type = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)

class GraphManager(models.Manager):
    def get_by_natural_key(self, name):
        return self.get(name=name)
class Graph(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    type = models.ForeignKey(GraphType)

class LineManager(models.Manager):
    def get_by_natural_key(self, name):
        return self.get(name=name)
class Line(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)

class GraphToLineManager(models.Manager):
    def get_by_natural_key(self, line, graph):
        return self.get(line=line,graph=graph)
class GraphToLine(models.Model):
    line = models.ForeignKey(Line)
    graph = models.ForeignKey(Graph)
    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('line', "graph"),)
```

And my YAML fixture is:

```
- model: graphs_container.GraphType
  pk: null
  fields:
    type: TimeSeries
- model: graphs_container.Graph
  pk: null
  fields:
    name: LikesOverTime
    type: [TimeSeries]
- model: graphs_container.Graph
  pk: null
  fields:
    name: UsersOverTime
    type: [TimeSeries]
- model: graphs_container.Line
  pk: null
  fields:
    name: NumUsers
- model: graphs_container.Line
  pk: null
  fields:
    name: NumLikes
```

But when trying to run `python manage.py loaddata sample_data.yaml`, I get the following error:

```
DeserializationError: [u"'['TimeSeries']' value must be an integer."]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'd try using json format and dump the data again.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to

- define `natural_key` method in your models
- have a manager with `get_by_natural_key` method
- actually attach the managers (`objects=GraphManager()`)

After playing with your code, I made it work:

```
class GraphTypeManager(models.Manager):
    def get_by_natural_key(self, type):
        return self.get(type=type)

class GraphType(models.Model):
    type = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    objects = GraphTypeManager()

    def natural_key(self):
        return (self.type,)  # must return a tuple

class GraphManager(models.Manager):
    def get_by_natural_key(self, name):
        return self.get(name=name)

class Graph(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    type = models.ForeignKey(GraphType)
    objects = GraphManager()
```

Dumping the data:

```
$ bin/django dumpdata index --indent=4 --natural > project/apps/fixtures_dev/initial_data.json
[
    {
        "pk": 1,
        "model": "index.graphtype",
        "fields": {
            "type": "asotuh"
        }
    },
    {
        "pk": 1,
        "model": "index.graph",
        "fields": {
            "type": [
                "asotuh"
            ],
            "name": "saoneuht"
        }
    }
]

bin/django loaddata project/apps/fixtures_dev/initial_data.json 
Installed 2 object(s) from 1 fixture(s)
```

Comment: You need to either show the traceback and the data that makes the error or re-create both model and fixtures. I can't see what's going wrong. What I show works perfectly on my side.

Comment: Oh, you're right, I actually didn't, though I thought it loaded. I re-checkend and found what was wrong: the manager has to be attached to the model with a special line, like: `objects = GraphTypeManager()`

Comment: According to the note in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/serialization/#serialization-of-natural-keys), you only need `natural_key()` for serialization, and you only need `get_by_natural_key()` for *de*serialization. However, [`build_instance()`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/0dd29209091280ccf34e07c9468746c396b7778e/django/core/serializers/base.py#L325), used by e.g. `serializers.deserialize()`, relies on both in order to `get` existing objects by natural key (also see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46999690)).